# Swap part of a value from one column to the other column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have one table:

> dbo.Product

Two columns:

```
SKU      Name
---      ----
100A-B   (F102397) 1 AFFF C-103
```

I want to swap the SKU(100A-B) with JUST PART of Name(F102397) without the parenthesis in the SKU column.

So it would be like:

```
SKU      Name
---      ----
F102397  (100A-B) 1 AFFF C-103
```

And just FYI, the "Name" column isn't always consistent. Meaning it wouldn't always be like "1 AFFF C-103". Sometimes it can be "1AFFFC-103" or "1AFFF C-103", etc...but with different values. Would you need to worry about the second half when there are spaces/no spaces?

Anyway of doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)
I'm working with SQL-Server 2005.

** **EDIT** **

More examples and what I'm trying to get from it.

Example of what most of the data looks like. Its a mess with the spaces in some of the SKU's but that's something I DON'T have the option of changing.

And I am keeping the () in the "Name" field.

```
SKU      Name
---      ----
100A-B   (F102397) 1 AFFF C-103
101 A-F  (F011889) TEST ITEM
101 U-X  (F060796) TEST ITEM 2
102A-B   (F102497) TEST ITEM 3
```

**RESULT**

```
SKU      Name
---      ----
F102397  (100A-B) 1 AFFF C-103
F011889  (101 A-F) TEST ITEM
F060796  (101 U-X) TEST ITEM 2
F102497  (102A-B) TEST ITEM 3
```

Comment: The portion you want to extract/swap is always in parentheses?

Comment: Looks like another reason regular expressions would be useful in SQL Server. This can absolutely be done with `PATINDEX`, `SUBSTRING` and `REPLACE`; it's not going to be difficult, but it's going to be ugly. Before we provide examples, perhaps you can provide more details on what you need to accomplish in case there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: I agree with the other comments ... please supply additional examples so that we can understand the scope. Also if either column is nullable, or might not contain parentheses or whatever other conditions are used to identify the substring, include those examples and explain what to do in those cases. It's easy to solve the rule, then later come all the exceptions, and this is more work for everyone...

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: get the code to parse the strings here, but create new columns to store the parts separately and fix this awful design once and for all.  use a computed column to concatenate these new columns back together if they are needed for old code to use.  whenever you try to combine multiple pieces of data within a single column you need to resort to crazy split and parse logic, which makes simple queries slow and difficult to write.  The real solution is to store each piece of data in its own column and concatenate them as necessary when you need to display them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the available [string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx). It is often possible to cook something up with those.

```
update dbo.Product 
set SKU = substring(Name, 2, charindex( ')', Name)-2),
    Name = stuff(Name, 2, charindex( ')', Name)-2, SKU)
```

This assumes that there are always a `(` at the beginning of the Name field. There will always be a `)` somewhere in the name field. Neither Name or SKU contain null values.
If that is not the case you have to specify in your question what you want the result to be.

If you only need to query the data instead of updating use a select statment.

```
select substring(Name, 2, charindex( ')', Name)-2),
       stuff(Name, 2, charindex( ')', Name)-2, SKU)
from YourTableName
```

Comment: @jwahr Try it out here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61652/swapit

Comment: @MickaelEriksson - Thanks so much, that helps a lot in where I need to go with it. Now my next question, this is going to sound probably be obvious to everyone else, but how would I go about looking for the data in my table(backup/test table)(300+ products) and applying what you just did but not actually updating the table? Just see results?

Comment: @jwahr - Updated answer with a `select` statement.

Comment: @MickaelEriksson - Thanks again for all your help. I kind of figured it before you posted your edit :) If I could Vote Up the answer I would but I can't or give you reps somehow because I'm new to the site.

Comment: @jwahr you are wellcome. You can accept the answer using the tick mark. But you should probably wait awhile to see if someone else has a better solution.